# How to delete extra information?

Tags: chessboard, skak

When I compile the following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{diagram}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\begin{document}
\begin{diagram}[4x4]
\pieces{}
\end{diagram}
\begin{diagram}[3x4]
\pieces{}
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

appears information that do not interest me. How to delete them?

Comment: This does not compile for me (please explain your compilation routine of complete the example). Don't know the packages, but does `\begin{diagram*}` exist? This would be the first thing I'd try in order to get rid of the numbers.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to use `xskak` instead of `skak` package?

Comment: If you exit \begin {diagram}, when complia disappears the Board

Comment: OK, `diagram*` does not work. Do you even need `skak` and `chessboard` for the picture you have shown us? Still can't compile if I leave `\pieces{}` empty

Comment: You can put any piece. I can compile like this, but the extra information continue to appear

Comment: ok, but then you should modify your MWE. Costed me 5 minutes to get it compiling. First solution: write `\begin{diagram}[4x4]
\specialdiagnum{}` to get rid of the number.

Comment: LaRiFaRi, I tried as you said but it didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands needed to get rid of the additional informations are described in the documentation of `diagram`.

`diagram` clashes with `skak` and `chessboard` as it tries to (re)define the command `\boardfont`. You can avoid the error by loading `chessboard` before `diagram` and "undefining" the command so that `diagram` can overwrite it. This won't affect `chessboard` but break the `\showboard` command of `skak`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\let\boardfont\undefinedcommand
\usepackage{diagram}

\begin{document}
\setboolean{showcomputer}{false}
\setboolean{piececounter}{false}
\specialdiagnum{}
\begin{diagram}[4x4]
\pieces{wKd3}
\end{diagram}

\newgame\mainline{1. e4} 
\chessboard
\showboard
\end{document}
```